# NHibernate Connection Pooling

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am considering using Fluent NHibernate for a new application with SQL Server 2008 and I am having trouble understanding the connection handling behavior I am seeing.

I am monitoring connections using sp_who2 and here is what I see:

1. When the SessionFactory is created, a single connection is opened.  This connection 
   seems to stay open until the app is killed.
2. No connection is opened when a new session is opened.  (That's ok, I understand NHibernate waits until the last moment to create database connections).
3. No new connection is opened even when I run a query through NHibernate.  I must assume it is using the connection created when the SessionFactory was created, which is still open.  I set a breakpoint after the query (before the session was closed), and no new sessions had appeared in sp_who.

Running an entire app through a single connection is not acceptable (obviously).  **How can I ensure each ISession gets its own connection?**  I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing here...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour that you see is nothing NHibernate specific - Connection pooling is default behaviour in SQL Server.
Even if it may sound awkward at first glance, it actually is a good thing because creating new connections and maintaining them is expensive.
(for more information, see the [Wikipedia article about connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool))

So there is no need to try to get NH to open a new connection for each session, because reusing existing connections actually improves SQL Server performance.