# NHibernate and ADO.NET Connection Pooling

Tags: .net, nhibernate, ado.net, connection-pooling

It seems that NHibernate does not pool ADO.NET database connections. Connections are only closed when the transaction is committed or rolled back. A review of the source code shows that there is no way to configure NHibernate so that it is closing connections when the ISession is disposed.

What was the intent of this behaviour? ADO.NET has connection pooling itself. There's no need to hold them open all the time within the transaction. With this behaviour are also unneccessaryly distributed transactions created. A possible workaround described in http://davybrion.com/blog/2010/05/avoiding-leaking-connections-with-nhibernate-and-transactionscope/ therefore does not work (at least not with NHibernate 3.1.0). I am using Informix. The same problem seems to exisit for every other database ([NHibernate Connection Pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686993/nhibernate-connection-pooling)).

Is there any other workaround or advice avoiding this problem?

Here's a unit test reproducing the problem:

```
  [Test]
  public void DoesNotCloseConnection()
  {
     using (SessionFactoryCache sessionFactoryCache = new SessionFactoryCache())
     {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10) }))
        {
           fixture.Setup(); // Creates test data

           System.Data.IDbConnection connectionOne;
           System.Data.IDbConnection connectionTwo;

           using (ISessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactoryCache.CreateFactory(GetType(), new TestNHibernateConfigurator()))
           {
              using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
              {
                 var result = session.QueryOver<Library>().List<Library>();
                 connectionOne = session.Connection;
              }
           }

           // At this point the first IDbConnection used internally by NHibernate should be closed

           using (ISessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactoryCache.CreateFactory(GetType(), new TestNHibernateConfigurator()))
           {
              using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
              {
                 var result = session.QueryOver<Library>().List<Library>();
                 connectionTwo = session.Connection;
              }
           }

           // At this point the second IDbConnection used internally by NHibernate should be closed

           // Now two connections are open because the transaction is still running
           Assert.That(connectionOne.State, Is.EqualTo(System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)); // Fails because State is still 'Open'
           Assert.That(connectionTwo.State, Is.EqualTo(System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)); // Fails because State is still 'Open'
        }
     }
  }
```

The disposing of the NHibernate-Session does nothing since we are still in a transaction

SessionImpl.cs:

```
public void Dispose()
    {
        using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
        {
            log.Debug(string.Format("[session-id={0}] running ISession.Dispose()", SessionId));
            if (TransactionContext!=null)
            {
                TransactionContext.ShouldCloseSessionOnDistributedTransactionCompleted = true;
                return;
            }
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
```

Injecting a custom ConnectionProvider will also not work since the ConnectionManager calling the ConnectionProvider has several preconditions checking that closing a connection within a transaction is not allowed.

ConnectionManager.cs:

```
public IDbConnection Disconnect() {
        if (IsInActiveTransaction)
            throw  new InvalidOperationException("Disconnect cannot be called while a transaction is in progress.");

        try
        {
            if (!ownConnection)
            {
                return DisconnectSuppliedConnection();
            }
            else
            {
                DisconnectOwnConnection();
                ownConnection = false;
                return null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure that AfterTransactionCompletion gets called since
            // it takes care of the locks and cache.
            if (!IsInActiveTransaction)
            {
                // We don't know the state of the transaction
                session.AfterTransactionCompletion(false, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, databases need the same connection in order to utilize a transaction. So I don't find it strange that it keeps a connection alive as long as a transaction is running? If the connection is returned to the pool, there is nothing that ensure that you will receive the same connection from the pool the second time.

Comment: However, in your concrete test, you are checking the underlying IdbConnection, which I assume is part of ADO.NET, and isn't it the ADO.NET connection pooling that you are testing in that case? What you should do is create two different sessions (from the same factory as well, make sure that is the case) and make sure that you receive the same connection.

Comment: At the begin of each transaction the Driver class (in my case OdbcDriver) creates a new DbConnection (OdbcConnection). This connection stays open the whole transaction which is unnecessary. The test I've written actually uses two different sessions from one SessionFactory.

Comment: I'm still not sure that checking .State is  fair test to make. Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.state.aspx it says: "Calling the State property on an open connection increases application overhead because each such call causes a SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_DEAD call to the underlying ODBC driver to determine whether the connection is still valid."  This indicates that a "Closed" connection might be a dead connection, therefor not reusable to the pool.

Comment: furthermore: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state.aspx says the following: "Indicates the state of the SqlConnection when the most recent network operation was performed on the connection." Which leads me to think that the State doesn't actually represent what the current state of the connection is in this case, and can not be used to make sure connections are available to the pool. And pooling can also be a driver feature, I know for a fact that Npgsql has built in connection pooling, and doesn't rely on ADO.NET for it.

Comment: But you can see in the NHibernate source code that the connection is created at the beginning of an transaction and closed when the transaction is finished. It stays open the whole transaction because nothing is done in the Dispose method of SessionImpl.

Comment: Yeah, well I don't see how a transaction would work unless you make it certain that you still use the same connection? It might be possible for some databases to share a transaction across multiple connections, but then how would NHibernate know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NHibernate has two "modes".

- Either you open the connection in your application, then it is up to the application to manage it. This "mode" is used when passing a connection to `sessionfactory.OpenSession(connection)`.
- Or the connection is created by NH. Then it is closed when the session is closed. This "mode" is used when not passing a connection to `sessionfactory.OpenSession()`

There is some support for `TransactionScope`. It is most probably using the first "mode". Probably the connection is not hold by NH, but by the transaction scope. I don't know exactly, I don't use environment transactions.

NH *is* using the ADO.NET connection pool by the way.

You can also disconnect the session using `ISession.Disconnect()` and reconnect using `ISession.Reconnect()`.

In the [documentation](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-10-transactions-and-concurrency#10%282E%295%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Session_disconnection) you find:

> The method ISession.Disconnect() will disconnect the session from the
>   ADO.NET connection and return the connection to the pool (unless you
>   provided the connection).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think you're wrong with the "second" mode. When the session is disposed the connection stays open. As you can see in the code snipped I posted above (ConnectionManager.cs) it's not possible to disconnect/reconnect within a transaction scope. In the link you provided it is also said that you must first commit/abort the transaction before you can disconnect/reconnect again. The connection (IDbConnection) is controlled by the ConnectionManager class as a private member and not by the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding the following settings to your connection string.

```
Pooling=true; 
Min Pool Size=3;
Max Pool Size=25;
Connection Lifetime=7200;
Connection Timeout=15;
Incr Pool Size=3;
Decr Pool Size=5;
```

Pooling:  enables pooling for your app

Min Pool:  The minimum number of connections to keep open even when all sessions are closed.

Max Pool:  The max number of connections the app will open to the DB.  When the max is reached it will wait for the number of seconds specified by Connection Timeout and then throw an exception.

Connection Timeout:  Maximum Time (in secs) to wait for a free connection from the pool

Connection Lifetime: When a connection is returned to the pool, its creation time is compared with the current time, and the connection is destroyed if that time span (in seconds) exceeds the value specified by Connection Lifetime. A value of zero (0) causes pooled connections to have the maximum connection timeout.

Incr Pool Size:  Controls the number of connections that are established when all the connections are used.

Decr Pool Size:  Controls the number of connections that are closed when an excessive amount of established connections are unused.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance